# How to know the cloud object name by its UUID or by its name get its UUID

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

For specify this question,I create a temporary object in folder `tem`,and named it `identity`:

```
CloudDeploy[
 FormFunction[{"x" -> <|"Input" -> "Apple"|>}, 
  Identity], "tem/identity"]
```

> `CloudObject[https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user***/tem/identity]`

I get it with name form.We can check it by

```
CloudObjects["tem"]
```

> `CloudObject[https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/f0c5a7f1-7124-4a0b-8c64-cd0ebae72350]`

I get it with UUID form,I promise this both forms is on behalf of a same cloud object.But If I just know the UUID,how to know its name?And vice-versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through `` Names["System`Cloud*"] ``, I found `CloudObjectInformation`. I *think* this is what you're looking for.

```
obj = CloudDeploy[
  FormFunction[{"x" -> <|"Input" -> "Apple"|>}, Identity], 
  "tem/identity"];
```

Here's its UUID:

```
CloudObjectInformation[obj, "UUID"]
```

> ```
> "8112805a-013b-46b9-bdc4-2b20b037d795"
> ```

Here's its path:

```
CloudObjectInformation[obj, "Path"]
```

> ```
> "user-****/tem/identity"
> ```

If I only know the UUID and want the path:

```
uuid = "8112805a-013b-46b9-bdc4-2b20b037d795";
CloudObjectInformation[CloudObject[URLBuild[{$CloudBase, "objects", uuid}]], "Path"]
```

> ```
> "user-****/tem/identity"
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your undocumentational function,I don't know how do you guess the "Path",I just have tried `CloudObjects["tem"]["Properties"]` ,Inspiring. :)

Comment: @yode I ran `CloudObjectInformation` with 1 argument first and it gave a whole table of data, with uuid and path as elements.

Comment: Since WL 12.1, the `Information` function now does the same thing, and is calling `CloudObjectInformation` under the hood. In the documentation you can see this under Examples > Scope > System Objects.