# Unexpected behavior of CloudObjects

Tags: bugs, files-and-directories, filtering, wolfram-cloud

In [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128106/how-to-know-the-cloud-object-name-by-its-uuid-or-by-its-name-get-its-uuid) I create a temporary object like follow

```
CloudDeploy[
 FormFunction[{"x" -> <|"Input" -> "Apple"|>}, 
  Identity], "tem/identity"]
```

> `CloudObject[https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user***/tem/identity]`

I have to say I just creat one object in folder `tem`, but when I run:

```
CloudObjects["tem", FormFunction]
```

I get a lots `CloudObject`. Actually I just use the fourth usage of [CloudObjects](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudObjects.html):

> CloudObjects[dir,type]

It is a bug of `CloudObjects` or I miss something?

Comment: @Kuba Yes,I have.After you confirmed. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug, here is a work-around:

```
Select[
 CloudObjects["/tem"],
 CloudObjectInformation[#, "MIMEType"] === "application/vnd.wolfram.expression.form" &
]
```

This is for `FormFunction`, for `ApiFunction` it ends up with `.api`. You will have to try what are mime types specs for object types you are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

It is comfirmed a bug(RE: [CASE:3732853]).I get a response just now

> Thank you for contacting Wolfram Technical Support.
>
> It's unclear why the CloudObjects expression is returning multiple objects when it should be 1.
>
> It has been reported on your behalf, to our developers.